# Is it a correct statement?

Tags: conditional-constructions

So basically I am trying to brush up my English with complex sentences and I got this one on internet so is it correct statement??I mean did and tomorrow used in same sentence....

> If sun didn't come up tomorrow, we wouldn't have any life on earth

Answer (score 4):

> If the sun didn't come up tomorrow, we wouldn't have any life on earth.

This is fine. The past-form verbs don't indicate tense but 'unreality'. Compare a version with present-form verbs:

> If the sun doesn't come up tomorrow, we won't have any life on earth.

That suggests that there is a real possibility that the sun will not come up tomorrow, which is pretty far-fetched! We shift the verbs into their past forms to indicate that we don't think that that's likely to happen.

Comment: I think this "past denoting unreal future" usage is at least *slightly* "off". Superficially it looks like a "poor man's subjunctive" used to avoid the somewhat stilted *If the sun **weren't to** come up tomorrow, earth would be lifeless.* But your point re "explicit future" implying *real possibility* gives pause for thought. I think OP's context is an unusual one where the fact of the sun *always* coming up the next day (whether in the past, present, or future) is a "timeless" aspect of reality in general.

Comment: Compare *If I didn't work on Sunday I wouldn't earn enough to pay the rent.* That's fine by my, but I have some misgivings about *If I didn't work **next** Sunday I wouldn't...*, which it seems to me creates confusion as to the timeframe being referenced. The implication is something like *If it were not the case (now) that I expect to work **on some defined day in the future**...* By the same token, OP's example implies *If it were not **now** true that the sun **will** rise tomorrow*. It's true we do use this construction, but it's at the very least "questionable".